# How remove columns with same values (dplyr::select)?

Tags: r

I have a data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c('col', NA, 1), 
  y = c('s', NA, 3), 
  w = c(0, 0, 0), 
  z = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)
)

     x    y w    z
1  col    s 0 <NA>
2 <NA> <NA> 0 <NA>
3    1    3 0 <NA>
```

First, I want remove the `w` column (all values `0`). The expected result is:

```
     x    y    z
1  col    s <NA>
2 <NA> <NA> <NA>
3    1    3 <NA>
```

Second, I want remove the `z` column (all values `NA`). The expected result is:

```
     x    y w
1  col    s 0
2 <NA> <NA> 0
3    1    3 0
```

I try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(.data = ., is.na)
```

> Error: Result 1 must be a single logical, not a logical vector of length 3

**I want use this `select` only, without prefix (`all`, `at`, `if`)**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `select` `where` number of unique values is greater than 1.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(where(~n_distinct(.) > 1))

#     x    y
#1  col    s
#2 <NA> <NA>
#3    1    3
```

Comment: What if I want to remove only the Column with missing data?

Comment: You can do `df %>% select(where(~any(!is.na(.))))` Or `df %>% select(where(~!all(is.na(.))))`

Comment: I tried: `library(dplyr) library(magrittr) df %>% 
  select(.data = ., where(fn = ~ ! equals(e1 = ., e2 = 0)))` to remove column with `0`s. But, doesn't work.

Comment: Similar to `NA` values you can remove column with all 0's as `df %>% select(where(~!all(. == 0)))` Or `df %>% select(where(~any(. != 0)))`

Comment: Doesn't work. See: Error: `where()` must be used with functions that return `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Comment: If you have `NA` values remove them `df %>% select(where(~any(. != 0, na.rm = TRUE)))`. If you want to keep columns with all `NA` values `df %>% select(where(~any(. != 0, na.rm = TRUE) | all(is.na(.))))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Filter` in `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1, df)
#     x    y
#1  col    s
#2 <NA> <NA>
#3    1    3
```